# Who am I if I am controlled by someone?

Tags: riddle

I am always on someone's cam,
He controlls the way I am.

I am tall,
And I listen to mall,

I am very fat,
Unlike a bat.

I can light a fuse,
Or abuse,
I can gather food,
Or chop down wood,
I can mine,
Or cut through slime,
I can build,
Or sell to a guild.

You can change my look for fame,
But my sizes will remain the same.

Who am I ?

Comment: *You could at least **solve** this riddle instead of **downvoting** it.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're

> the PC from Minecraft -- I think his name is Steve

I am always on someone's cam,
He controlls the way I am.

> Veedrac explained this -- on a computer screen, the player controls you

I am tall,
And I listen to mall,

> You are taller than some of the other creatures (source: Minecraft Dimensions, http://ata4.info/mcdim/).  "mall" is one of the music discs in Minecraft (source: Minecraft Wiki, http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki)

I am very fat,
Unlike a bat.

> Again according to Minecraft Dimensions, bats are basically half a meter in all dimensions, but the PC is a meter wide

I can light a fuse,

> In Minecraft TNT has a fuse

Or abuse,

> This could mean semi-cheat stuff ("abuse" the mechanisms), using abusive language in chat, or just the fact that you're beating up/killing creatures

I can gather food,

> Minecraft contains food

Or chop down wood,

> Minecraft contains wood

I can mine,

> Yep, you can

Or cut through slime,

> Minecraft contains slime

I can build,

> Yep, you can

Or sell to a guild.

> I think only mods have guilds, but a lot of people play Minecraft with a mod, so.

You can change my look for fame,
But my sizes will remain the same.

> Different player skins are available but they don't change the PC's abilities/size

Who am I ?

> See the top of this answer

Comment: take the screenshot of his comment...before he, say, delete it maybe...:p nice answer...

Comment: I'm actually gonna delete part of the answer because it's not very good spirited.

Comment: You got it right! The answer is correct, except one thing related to the "guild". (But the final answer is still right; marked as accepted) "Guild" meant trading to villagers. But you've guessed the hard-to-guess "mall" thing.

Comment: What comment are you talking about? @manshu

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not-entirely-finished answer.

> An RPG character that's a member of a race like the Pandaren (WoW) or Baraka (TERA)

I am always on someone's cam,
He controlls the way I am.

> "cam" meaning computer monitor. The player controls the character using this.

I am tall,
And I listen to mall,

I am very fat,
Unlike a bat.

> These are tall and fat races. There's either a bat-like character or enemy that's thinner. For reference, Googling for bat with the RPG name gives [a comparatively thin-looking giant bat for WoW](http://www.wow-petopia.com/images/skin_pix/batskinbrown01_v2.jpg).
>
>  "listen to mall" probably refers to some NPC or god named "Mall" or similar that the character follows. Nothing comes up in searches so far, though.

I can light a fuse,

> [Quest item](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Quest:A_Short_Fuse)

Or abuse,

> PKing

I can gather food,
Or chop down wood,
I can mine,

> Standard MMORPG actions

Or cut through slime,

> Basic MMORPG encounter

I can build,
Or sell to a guild.

> More standard MMORPG actions

You can change my look for fame,
But my sizes will remain the same.

> Equipment gives bonuses, is vital to progressing in these games and is the main customization point of a character. However, the underlying character shape is pretty much invariant.

Disclaimer

> I haven't played an MMORPG in ages, and I've never played the ones mentioned here.

Comment: The only thing right is that it's a game character, but **not MMORPG.**